# When debugging React v18 source code, I installed @babel/preset-flow as prompted, but I still get an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

Recently, I wanted to debug the source code of React v18 locally. The main operations I performed are as follows:
1.Downloaded the source code of React from GitHub and generated a build file locally;

```
build
     ....
     oss-experimental
     oss-stable
     ...
```

2. Entered the /build/oss-stable/react and /build/oss-stable/react-dom directories of oss-stable and created links using yarn link;
3. Created a project named react-debug using react-create-app, installed dependencies, executed yarn link react and react-dom, and started the project, but encountered an error message;

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: Support for the experimental syntax 'flow' isn't currently enabled (11:8):

   9 |
  10 | // Keep in sync with https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/main/lib/react.js
> 11 | export type StatelessFunctionalComponent<P> =
     |        ^
  12 |   React$StatelessFunctionalComponent<P>;
  13 | export type ComponentType<-P> = React$ComponentType<P>;
  14 | export type AbstractComponent<

Add @babel/preset-flow (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-preset-flow) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-flow (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-flow) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
...
```

4.Installed @babel/preset-flow and @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types according to the prompt, but still encountered the error shown in the figure;

5.Configured babel.

```
 "babel": {
    "plugins":["@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types",
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",{ "legacy": true }]],
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-flow"]
  }
```

Note: To ensure that the configuration in babel has taken effect, I tested the @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators plugin separately, and it worked, but @babel/preset-flow and @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types did not work. Please help me with this problem.